# MVC exclude controller usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, routes, overriding

I have created a 'template' project A which has 10 controllers ( partial class ).
All these controllers are packed in a nuget package and are consumed by projects B, C & D. The nuget generates the controllers in the folder `controllers/_core` so they are nicely stored separately. The nuget package does **not** have a reference to the dll of project A.

**Now to get down to the problem;** 
It could be that one of the controllers that are generated need to be modified. By adding a second partial we could add some logic, but it could be that we need to override an existing method to add logic inside the method. Because of this ( and because of the reason I added below ) I was thinking to inherit from these base controllers. When we inherit a base controller it should be excluded by MVC.

**Example**: Image PersonController was created in the controllers/_core folder by using the nuget package and every method is virtual.
We will then create a `_PersonController` in the controllers folder that inherits from PersonController and for simplicity sake only the index method is overriden. At this time we want to change the routing so localhost/Person/index ends up in the index method of the `_PersonController` and not that of the `PersonController`. `PersonController` should be completely ignored.

**Is my only option to add a custom route each time we need to override? Or are there better solutions for this kind of problem ( custom MVC controller factory? )? 
+ how do I define such routing?**

**Extra reason why I was thinking to inherrit:**
Every time we do an update of the nuget package it'll try to override all the changes made to the controllers that were generated in the consumer projects B, C & D.

Kind regards,

Yannick

Comment: if you have same name action than are you not getting ambiguous actions?

Comment: Everything in the base controller ( PersonController ) will be virtual and the _PersonController will override.

Answer (score 6):

You can go with controller inheritance.

### ASP.NET core

To ignore unnecessary controllers you need to implement `IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>` or derive from `ControllerFeatureProvider` :

```
public class MyControllerFeatureProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider
{
    protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        var isController = base.IsController(typeInfo);
        if (isController)
        {
            //overriding isController value
        }
        return isController;
    }
}
```

Then at your `Starup.ConfigureServices` you need to replace the default `ControllerFeatureProvider`:

```
services.AddMvc()
.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
{
    var controllerFeatureProvider =
        manager.FeatureProviders
            .Single(p => p.GetType() == typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider));
    manager.FeatureProviders[manager.FeatureProviders.IndexOf(controllerFeatureProvider)] =
       new Attributes.MyControllerFeatureProvider();
});
```

### ASP.NET MVC 5 and earlier

In your particular case you can go with namespaces list on the route registration and setting `UseNamespaceFallback` to `false` to ignore other namespaces:

```
var myRoute  = routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new [] {"Namespace1", "Namespace2"}
    );

myRoute.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```